# Get windows user from connection string

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

For a trigger in SQL Server 2008R2 I need to know the user who inserted, updated or deleted the record.

As different users log in with the same connection string I do not know who is really logged in to the server (I use SQL authentication with the same UID and I grant access through the Access database!!).

I would like if possible to add a variable to the connection string such as `Application Name=myrealusername` but it seems that from Access VBA I cannot add this Parameter.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the **real** username who's logged in to pass the username to the trigger?

Comment: If you need the REAL username, use Windows Authentication.

Comment: If all your sql connections are made with same user then sql has no way to know. If you switch to windows authentication you can tell but with the current way your application works you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try recording the `HOST_NAME()` to capture the instance the query was executed from. If every user has it's own PC, it's probably one of your best guesses if you don't plan on using Windows Authentication.

More details: [HOST_NAME() MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx)

Obviously the only *real* solution would be to use Windows Authentication.

Comment: Thanks, together with a table Decoding HOST_NAME into User I get the Information I Need!

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows authentication and try using

```
select suser_name()
```

Comment: No, all my attemps with CURRENT_User, suser_Name(), etc. bring the Login user which is not the "real" user.